# Create a Linux Standard Base LSB tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Technically, this may overlap with the Linux tag. However, in practice, in most questions and answers Linux do not necessarily mean LSB, but more something like LSB + GNU, and sometimes even distro specifics. Beginners don't even know what the LSB is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[lsb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lsb) Done. I'm far too lazy to go about adding it all over the place, or improving the tag wiki from what I copied from SO.

Comment: Thanks, that does it for me.